# Insert new row in Excel using OpenXml with specified columns

Tags: c#

This code is working fine but i want to do that i have 3 sheets in excel file and all sheets
have  different columns size , suppose first sheet have 5 columns second have 3 and third have
7 so on the basis of sheets i want to insert new row. Like if first sheet have 5 columns then data
insert only in  5 columns if second have 3 then only 3 values insert like that. So, can any one guide
me to do that.

```
   using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, Filemode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
        FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
     SpreadSheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false);
     SharedStringTable sharedStringTable = 
     document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
     string cellValue = null;

     foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetPart in document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.Reverse())
     {
       int cnt = document.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.count();
       foreach (SheetData sheetData in worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>())
       {
         if (sheetData.HasChildren)
         {
           foreach (Row row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                Row row = new Row();
                row.Append(ConstructCell("firstvalue",CellValues.String));
                sheetData.AppendChild(row);
               WorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                   }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
    document.Close();

  Public static Cell ConstructCell(string value , CellValues datatype)
  {
    return new Cell(){CellValue = new CellValue(value),DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues> 
   (datatype)};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I done it.

```
    //Replace this from

            Row row = new Row();
            row.Append(ConstructCell("firstvalue",CellValues.String));
            sheetData.AppendChild(row);
           WorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

    //To this one ::
     var rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>;
     int rwCnt = rows.Count();
     var clCnt = rows.First().ChildElements.Count();
     for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)
        {
          Row row  = new Row();
          for(j = 0; j < clCnt; j++)
            {
              row.Append(
                       ConstructCell("firstvalue",CellValues.String)
                   )
              }
           sheetData.AppendChild(row);
           WorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
```